# Can firebase server timestamps be written without making two requests?

Tags: rest, firebase

The Firebase REST API [describes how to write server values](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-server-values) (currently only timestamps are supported) at a location, but it appears that one must submit a separate request in order to do this. Is there (or has there been planned) any way of setting timestamps (like createdAt) at the same time one submits other data? Seems like this would really help reduce traffic and improve performance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure, this is possible. The documentation is admittedly a little unclear, but all you need to do is include the `{".sv": "timestamp"}` object as part of your JSON payload. Here's an example that saves it to a key `timestamp`.

`curl -X PUT -d '{"something":"something", "timestamp":{".sv": "timestamp"}}' https://abc.firebaseio-demo.com/.json`

Comment: Thanks @Ossama. Just tested it and it worked. Would be nice if the docs were clearer about this.

Comment: I'm not able to make this work with the current API.