# Firebase: record server side timestamp (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, firebase, timestamp, record, firebase-realtime-database

I am unsure on how to create automatically a time stamp at server side in Firebase.

Here is how I create my record:

```
NSMutableDictionary * dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSString * userId = [self determineUserId];

[[[_ref child:@"records"] child:userId] updateChildValues:dictionary];
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26129077/can-firebase-server-timestamps-be-written-without-making-two-requests) that suggests the following, however I am unsure how to translate that into Objective-C:

> curl -X PUT -d '{"something":"something", "timestamp":{".sv":
>   "timestamp"}}'

How do I translate this into Objective-C?

```
 "timestamp":{".sv": "timestamp"}
```

Is this the right approach?

I found also this Q/A in [Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485715/how-to-include-a-server-side-timestamp-in-swift).

Answer (score 3):

From the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#server-timestamps):

```
FIRDatabaseReference *userLastOnlineRef = [[FIRDatabase database] referenceWithPath:@"users/joe/lastOnline"];
[userLastOnlineRef onDisconnectSetValue:[FIRServerValue timestamp]];
```

The `onDisconnect` part is irrelevant (just happened to be in the sample I copied this from). You're looking for `FIRServerValue timestamp`.

Comment: Hello Frank, Thanks for the reply. I find this confusing. The previous documentation did not mention the "onDisconnect" phase. All I want to do is to save the timestamp of when the value is actually written in the server. So why is the method here used in association with onDisconnect?

Comment: The `onDisconnect` is not needed. I just happened to copy it from that sample. All you need is `FIRServerValue timestamp` from https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_server_value

Comment: Thanks. Would you be able to update the answer so I can accept it as final? It worked!